# Can I enumerate the exports of a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the following, is `values` a normal object in `file-2.js`?

```
// file-1.js
export {
    FOO,
    BAR
} from '~/my-values';

// file-2.js
import * as values from '~/file-1';

// what is `values` here? an object instance?
```

I ask because I want to use something like `values.hasOwnProperty('FOO')` and rollup raised the following error:

```
'hasOwnProperty' is not exported by 'file-1.js'
```

Side question: is there a convenient way to test code using the import and export keywords? To the best of my knowledge Chrome dev tools to not support them in snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [module namespace exotic objects](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects). They being exotic means that they are not exactly normal objects (they have different internals).

They also do not have `Object.prototype` on their prototype chain, so you can't use `hasOwnProperty` but you should be able to use it with `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply` since they do have an internal method for [`[[ GetOwnProperty ]]`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects-getownproperty-p)

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values, 'FOO');
```

You can also use `Reflect.has` on it.

```
Reflect.has(values, 'FOO');
```

Also since the prototype is `null` you can pretty much just use `in` too:

```
'FOO' in values
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say X.js is the following:

```
export const t = 0;
export const t2 = 4;
export default w = -1;
var w3 = -9;
```

When you do import * as Y from X;

Basically you get all the exports from that file and you get to them by calling X.some var that has export. 
For example:

```
var t = X.t; // local t will be equal 0.
```

You cannot get the vars from X file without export (as they are locally set there.

You could also import the mentioned above code like this for example, by getting the values you need.

```
import {t} from X.js
var local_t = t; // local_t is set to 3
```

The export default means that if you import the file without saying with const or * you will get the default export value.
For example:

```
import something from X.js;
var _local = something; //_local equals -1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Can I enumerate the properties ("exports") of a module? I want to use something like `module.hasOwnProperty('moduleName');`