# object.hasOwnProperty is not a function when spying on es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

So I'm doing a little bit of experimental programming to ensure I understand how certain things work, and I'm coming across an error which I don't understand. I can't see any obvious solutions for this problem using Google or on here specifically.

I'm trying to confirm to myself exactly how `jest.spyOn()` works when applied to module imports. But right now the answer is that it just doesn't.

spy.js:

```
export const foo = () => {
  console.log("called foo");
};

export const bar = () => {
  console.log("called bar");
};
```

spy.spec.js:

```
import * as Foo from "./spy";
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

test("call foo", () => {
  jest.spyOn(Foo, "bar");
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I run this test, I get the following error: `TypeError: object.hasOwnProperty is not a function`. I'm running node v15.12.0.

Can somebody explain to my

1. Why this error occurs
2. What I can do to remove it

*Edit*

It has been suggested that the problem is to do with the module import lacking a `prototype` property. This is not the issue - see below

```
import * as Foo from "./spy";
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

test("SpyOn plain object", () => {
  const bar = { baz: () => {} };
  expect(bar.prototype).toBeUndefined(); // Pass
  jest.spyOn(bar, "baz"); // No error
});

test("SpyOn import", () => {
  expect(Foo.prototype).toBeUndefined(); // Pass
  jest.spyOn(Foo, "foo"); // Error!
});
```

Comment: "*I'm experimenting to ensure I understand how certain things work*" - are you trying to understand how modules work, or are you trying to understand how jest spies work, or how jest's ability to mock modules works?

Comment: "*It has been suggested that the problem is to do with the module import lacking a `prototype` property.*" - where? Can you link that suggestion please? And no, they didn't mean [the lack of a `.prototype` property, but the lack of a prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572). Module namespaces do not inherit from `Object.prototype`. `Foo.hasOwnProperty` is undefined.

Comment: @Bergi: My guess was the usage of arrow functions which lacks the prototype property, Ben was referring to my answer below.

Comment: @Thalaivar correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I debugged `spyOn` to see what happens.

Since `Foo` is an object of type `Module`, it doesn't have an `hasOwnProperty` method ([see this answer regarding module namespace exotic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46955142/3002584)).

Hence, `spyOn` throws in [the following line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L979) (the `object` is the module `Foo`):

```
const isMethodOwner = object.hasOwnProperty(methodName);
```

If we change it to:

```
const isMethodOwner = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, methodName);
```

It would work, but we'll encounter another error(s) in the code that follows, for example here:

```
object[methodName] = original;
```

Which throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'bar' of object '[object Module]'
```

So maybe it's "better" to just reassign `object`?:

```
object = Object.assign({}, object);
```

In which case the following test passes:

```
test("call bar", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Foo, "bar");
  spy();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the following test fails, though I can't tell if it should pass at all?:

```
test("call bar", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Foo, "bar");
  Foo.bar();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Let us open a jest issue?

Comment: `Cannot assign to read only property 'bar' of object '[object Module]'` means that intercepting `Foo.bar` by spying on `Foo` is not possible. This is not a Jest bug.

Comment: You want a link to an edited file? ok, added. As for the `Cannot assign` error, if jest can't intercept `Foo.bar`, then shouldn't it be regarded as a jest bug?

Comment: It's not a Jest bug, it's "works as intended" or "wontfix". Nothing can spy on an immutable object.

Comment: Added the link to the source file.

Comment: @OfirD thanks! It says I can award you the bounty in 5 hours, so I'll click the button later.

Answer (score 2):

I just added the missing method.

```
Foo.hasOwnProperty = () => Object.hasOwnProperty;
jest.spyOn(Foo, "foo")
```

Not ideal... but worked. I was using Vue and Jest and solved the error for me.